# Existence of linear fucntional

Tags: functional-analysis

$E$ is normed linear space, $x$ and $y$ are distinct points in E.
I need to prove there exists functional $f\in E^*$ such that $||f||=1$ and $f(x)\ne f(y)$.
I tried to find such functional on the hyperplane that contains $x$ and $y$ and then extend it to the whole space $E$, but I can't prove the norm of the functional equals 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with Hahn-Banach theorem ? (the "extension" one, as there is also a "separation" one)

It suffices to apply corollary 2 (see below) to $(x-y)$ and you are done since $x \neq y$ implies $\|x-y\| \neq 0$, so $|f(x-y)| \neq 0$ which implies
$$ f(x) \neq f(y).$$

**Hahn-Banach extension theorem (for continuous linear functional)**
Let $X$ be a normed space and let $Y \subset X$ be a space of $X$. If $g \in Y^*$ then there exists $f \in X^*$ such that $\|f\| = \|g\|$ and $f(y) = g(y)$ for all $y \in Y$.

**Corollary 1**
For all $x_0 \in X\backslash \{0\}$ there exists $f \in X^*$ with $\|f\| = 1$ such that $f(x) = \|x_0\|$.

**Proof of Corollary 1**

Consider $g : \text{span}(x_0)  \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defines by $g(\lambda x_0) := \lambda \|x_0\|$.

It's easy to check that it a linear functional. Moreover
$$| g(\lambda x_0) | = |\lambda| \|x_0\| = \|\lambda x_0\|.$$
By the theorem of Hahn-Banach $g$ has an extension $f$ to the whole of $X$. Therefore
$$ |f(x)| \leq \|x\|$$
for all $x \in X$ which means $\|f\| \leq 1$. But also
$$|f(x_0)| = |g(x_0)| = \|x_0\|$$
so $\|f\| =1$.

**Corollary 2**
For all $x \in X$
$$\|x\| = \sup\limits_{\substack{f \in X^*\\ \|f\| = 1}}|f(x)|.$$

**Proof of Corollary 2**

On the one hand, for all $f \in X^*$ with $\| f\| = 1$ we have
$$ |f(x)| \leq \|x\|.$$

On the other hand by Hahn-Banach extension theorem there exists $f \in X^*$ with $\|f\|$ such that $f(x) = \|x\|$.

Comment: Thank you M.G! I understood the proof. Thank you again!